# MySQL Change label value in select distinct and count

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRAD_ACAD,
COUNT(GRAD_ACAD) AS subtotal
FROM academicos
WHERE CCN REGEXP 'I|D65'
GROUP BY GRAD_ACAD
ORDER BY GRAD_ACAD
```

which results are:

```
GRAD_ACAD  subtotal
DOC          11
LIC           2
MTR           3
```

What i want to do is to change the values labels into the following:

```
GRAD_ACAD      subtotal
Doctorado        11
Licenciatura      2
Maestría          3
```

I have tried Case when like this but i can't get it to work:

```
SELECT DISTINCT GRAD_ACAD CASE GRAD_ACAD WHEN 'DOC' THEN 'doctorado' ELSE(SELECT GRAD_ACAD) END AS GRAD_ACAD,
COUNT(GRAD_ACAD) AS subtotal
FROM academicos
WHERE CCN REGEXP 'I|D65'
GROUP BY GRAD_ACAD
ORDER BY GRAD_ACAD
```

How can i fix this?

Comment: DISTINCT is redundant here.

Comment: you have to specify an actual condition in WHEN rather than just WHEN 'DOC'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to use `DISTINCT` here

```
SELECT  CASE GRAD_ACAD WHEN 'DOC' THEN 'doctorado' 
                 WHEN 'LIC' then 'Licenciatura'
                 WHEN 'MTR' then 'Maestria'
                 ELSE GRAD_ACAD end,
COUNT(GRAD_ACAD) AS subtotal
FROM academicos
WHERE CCN REGEXP 'I|D65'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1;
```

Notice that I used `group by 1` and `order by 1` which specify the first selected field, instead of repeating the case in both clause.

Answer (score 2):

`case GRAD_ACAD when 'DOC' then 'Doctorado' 
                when 'LIC' then 'Licenciatura' 
                when 'MTR' then 'Maestria' 
                else GRAD_ACAD end`

you'll need to put the same clause in both your `SELECT` and your `GROUP BY`